How to start a Solana-Validator?
How to start a Solana Validator and what are the requirements of running a Solana Validator node and how much a Solana Validator can make ?

You can find the requirements here:
https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/prerequisites
You need around 1 sol per day for votes. So you need around 5k self stakes sol to be profitable or 50k sol with a 10% fee.
There is a validator delegation program from the solana foundation that will stake to your validator to get you off the ground:
https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/validator-initiatives
